# How can I remove characters in a string after a specific special character in snowflake sql?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a url column in my database. I want to remove all characters after ? .

`select regexp_replace(page_url,'?(.*)', '') as clean_url from demo`

But I'm getting the following error:
Invalid regular expression: '?(.*)', no argument for repetition operator: ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `LEFT` and `CHARINDEX`:

```
SELECT IFF(CHARINDEX('?', page_url)>0,
           LEFT(page_url, CHARINDEX('?', page_url)),
           page_url) AS clean_url 
FROM demo
```

Answer (score 1):

`?` is a regular expression match token to a repeat prior token and thus to match it explicitly it needs to be escaped: `\?`

[as per the doc](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-regexp.html#escape-characters-and-caveats)'s:

> To escape meta-characters (as mandated by the POSIX standard). For example, to force the regular expression meta-characters * and ? to be treated as literals rather than as meta-characters, use `\*` and `\?`.

BUT if you are entering it via the SQL parser, it will need to be double escaped. thus need to be `\\?`

```
select
    page_url
    ,regexp_replace(page_url,'\\?(.*)', '') as clean_url 
from values
    ('https://example.com/page.html?parameter1')
    t(page_url);
```

gives:

| PAGE_URL | CLEAN_URL |
| --- | --- |
| https://example.com/page.html?parameter1 | https://example.com/page.html |